# How to record screen while testing in Robot framework Appium?

Tags: appium, robotframework

I'm looking the way how to record screen on Robot framework Appium.I've check on Appium Robot Framework Doc but it doesn't describe about it but i have try to write custom lib with python but it's doesn't support.

```
import os
import subprocess
from appium import webdriver
from robot.api import logger
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '12.3.2'
desired_caps['bundleId'] = 'xxxxxx'
desired_caps['udid'] = 'xxxxxxx'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'iPhone'
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub",desired_caps)
def start_screen_recording():
    driver.start_recording_screen()
def stop_screen_recording():
    filepath = os.path.join("/Users/keo.sidara/Desktop/Mobile_Test/testcases/regression", "screen_recording_110918-205655.mp4")
    warning_message(filepath)
    payload = driver.stop_recording_screen()
    with open(filepath, "wb") as fd:
        fd.write(base64.b64decode(payload))
```

and i got message

> [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'invalid session id' to NoSuchDriverError
>   [W3C (1530275d)] Encountered internal error running command:
>   NoSuchDriverError:

Anybody experience with it ? please share me. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to run a regular Robot Framework Appium "hello world" example using this device?

Answer (score 1):

The Appium documentation on the start Recording method is [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/recording-screen/start-recording-screen/).

In the AppliumLibrary documentation the [source code](https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary/blob/master/AppiumLibrary/keywords/_applicationmanagement.py#L39) for keyword [Open Application](http://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html#Open%20Application)  shows that the keyword returns number of the application in the registry.

This means that there is no AppiumLibrary supported way of retrieving the webdriver. This means that a modification to the original library is needed. This has been done already in a fork: **nichotined / [robotframework-appiumlibrary](https://github.com/nichotined/robotframework-appiumlibrary/commit/0b642611a78c805a34155df6276ea9b6bc33e99e)**

Removing the original library from your python installation and installing this one, you then have access to the keyword Get Current Application that returns the driver. Now, you can use the below approach or add another keyword yourself in the same fashion to create the custom Start and Stop Screenrecording.

As I don't have a working Appium Setup, I'm unable to validate this myself:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    AppiumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
    Open Application    
    ...    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
    ...    alias=Myapp1
    ...    platformName=iOS
    ...    platformVersion=7.0   
    ...    deviceName='iPhone Simulator'
    ...    app=your.app

    ${driver}  Get Current Application


    Call Method    ${driver}    start_recording_screen
```

Comment: i have try follow your solution but i got "Object 'AppiumLibrary' does not have method '_current_application'." so what is going on ?

Comment: Did the first approach work for you? I wasn't that sure about the second.

Comment: The first one also not work too because maybe we pass wrong ${driver}. i try to log output of ${driver} it's value = "1" ,So it's show me error "Object '1' does not have method 'start_recording_screen'." So do you have another solution?

Comment: Updated the answer with a reference to a Fork.

Comment: i'm have uninstall previous Appiumlibrary and start clone repo you have share and install it , but the problem is still exist .it's can't find the keyword Get Current Application. Have no idea :)

Answer (score 1):

As of `robotframework-appiumlibrary v1.5.0.6`, support for screen recording has been implemented. Can check https://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html#Start%20Screen%20Recording.

Happy Coding!

Comment: yeah cheer! https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary/issues/273

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Robot Framework before but I tried a lot of ways to record with the appium driver but I couldn't get it working. The only solution that I found was to use ADB SHELL Commands to record the screen of a device. You should have in mind that not all devices are capable of getting their screen recorded.

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/test.mp4 --size 480x720 #To start recording
```

Once you kill the process above you can get the video from the device with these commands

```
adb pull /sdcard/test.mp4 "C:/"

adb shell rm /sdcard/test.mp4
```

Comment: Does this work with iOS, as is shown in the example?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Only with Android. Sorry, I didn't notice that it was for iOS.